# How to implement an opaque BackgroundCssClass for a ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to make the background of my `ModalPopupExtender` (when the modal window is shown) to be exactly like it is in [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) example.

How do I achieve this?

My code:

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnInvisibleTarget" PopupControlID="pnlCert" 
 EnableViewState="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" />
```

And, so far I've tried:

```
.ModalBackground
{
    filter: alpha(opacity=55); 
    -moz-opacity: .55; 
    background-color:#EEE;
}
```

And:

```
.ModalBackground
{
    background-color:#fff;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7px;
}
```

But neither work. Both just set the background with the colors specified. No opacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
.ModalBackgroud
{
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too. I'll mark this as the solution when I'm allowed to.